# Deriving Xpath for a text using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am not able to derive the xpath for the following Text "Payment complete. Your policy will be generated soon". I have tried using the default xpath by directly copying the same but it throws the following error during execution
invalid selector:

```
The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: not sure how to accept answers... I am not aware of how stackoverflow works..sorry for the inconvenience caused

Comment: And again, we need a link or entire XML/HTML code here

Answer (score 1):

The xpath expression...

```
//*[@id="__next"]/div/div1/div[2]/div1/div1/span/text( )
```

...returns a *Text Node* where as [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) expects a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139).

---

To locate the element with text ***Payment complete. Your policy will be generated soon*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH 1*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()[contains(.,'Payment complete')]]")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH 2*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Your policy will be')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```